# Вывод непонятного массива вместо объекта PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$connect=mysql_pconnect ("localhost","admin","admin");
$db="news";
mysql_select_db ( $db );
$idReq = mysql_query('SELECT id FROM news_table WHERE id');
$id = mysql_fetch_object($idReq);
print_r ($id);
 ?>
```

В теории этот код должен выводить id, но выводит

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 )
```

Comment: в теории он все правильно делает http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-object.php

Comment: на будущее, еще прочитайте там же в красном блоке информацию, будет полезна

Comment: `echo $id->id;`

Answer (score 1):

Все таки напишу ответом, данная функция работает корректно прочитайте [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-object.php), но советую в данной документации обратить внимание на красный блок, так как данное расширение уже устарело.

Если все же решились использовать данную функцию, то для доступа к данному объекту, как в комментарии написали, нужно использовать следующую конструкцию

```
$id->id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$connect=mysql_pconnect ("localhost","admin","admin");
$db="news";
mysql_select_db ( $db );
$idReq = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM news_table ORDER BY `news_table`.`id` ASC');
while ($id = mysql_fetch_object($idReq)) {
  echo $id -> id;

}
mysql_result($idReq);
 ?>
```

Спасибо всем, разобралась